# Html div and Javascript mouseover not functioning well

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover

These are my codes:

**PHP**

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#panel').mouseover(function(){
$('.strip').css("background-image","url(images/Strip_orange.png)");
});
$('#panel').mouseout(function(){
$('.strip').css("background-image","url(images/Player_Strip.png)");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div class="panel"  >
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="strip">1</div>
        <div class="strip" >Hello World!!!</div>
        <div class="strip">HTML</div>
        <div class="strip">numeric</div>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
    <img src="images/desc.png">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Css**

```
#container {
clear:both;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;left:35px;top:40px;
width: 800px;
padding-bottom:200px;
}
#panel
{
clear: both;
position:relative;left:65px;bottom:329px;

}
.strip{
float:left;
margin:0;
padding: 8px 0 0 0;
width:160px;
text-align:center;
height: 20px;
font-size:14px;
border-right: 1px solid #ced9ec;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1db;
position:relative;top:400px;left:53px;
}
```

There are two problems I am facing:

- Div strip is coming out of the div panel and I am not able to solve
  that problem.
- Mouseover should work for single row. If I hover
  over one row that row should change the image to Strip_orange.png.
  Instead, my entire div is turning Strip_orange.png on hover.

Comment: if it's just the background-image you want to change on mouseover, CSS :hover would do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

According to what you want your mark-up is bit wrong. I know, all developers hate tables, but when you really have a table then do not hesitate to use "table" ( I follow the rule : if i can insert the data inside an excel sheet then is a table ).

Also another problem is that you used `class="panel"` but in css you declared `#panel` ( # = id );

I did an example for you [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ryJBV/1/) . I did not understood what are you doing with player_strip background. 
Also I recommend you to learn about [clearfix](http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/) to understand exactly what happens with your "leaving" divs. I don't know exactly what you want to do but I am sure you do not need so much `position: relative;`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but wrt panel in my code i have given <div id="panel"> and i can not use table because i have a requirement for div and strictly no tables allowed.                                     The problem here is strip is a image that i am using as rows so my rows are getting out of the div panel despite all adjustments.

Comment: And Player_Strip is a image that is seen earlier and on hover using mouseover it changes to Strip_orange.

Comment: I have been working for about 5 years in web development but it first time when i heard that i can't use tables when i really have to put tables. Anyway, i found another solution for you : http://fiddle.jshell.net/ryJBV/2/ .